# How to get results from 2 derived tables in one row?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the data from 2 derived tables in one row if possible.
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table users (
  userId INT
);

INSERT INTO users (userId) VALUES (1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT userId, firstTable.name, secondTable.text 
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES 
    ROW('FirstName'),
    ROW('secondName')
) firstTable(name)

INNER JOIN (
    VALUES 
    ROW('Some Text'),
    ROW('Some other text')
) secondTable(text)
 
WHERE userId = 1;
```

| userId | name | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | secondName | Some Text |
| 1 | FirstName | Some Text |
| 1 | secondName | Some other text |
| 1 | FirstName | Some other text |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9phZ7EpRUS4FNRBZRdSYZa/144)

This query returns a Cartesian product (I think) but I need to return the data in one row, or rather one row for every pair of values in the derived tables this:

| userId | name | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstName | Some Text |
| 1 | SecondName | Some other text |

Comment: This sound to be an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) Why would you do this?

Comment: Corrected fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9phZ7EpRUS4FNRBZRdSYZa/143

Comment: or if you wants only one row, how you determine firstname or secondName? Or Why are you hardcoding the whole thing? It would be easier if you explain what do you really need

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I want to use the results from this query to bulk insert data, so I'm doing a INSERT INTO ... SELECT, where some values like userId the same for every query.

Comment: @RDU Oh, I understand now. Sorry. I know your question was already answered but if you are not working directly with MySQL I would suggest make the bulk insert directly as INSERT INTO o from some ORM entities. Even I had to work in this way in Excel, making a "CONCAT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a column which sets the relation between the rows.

```
CREATE TABLE users ( userId INT ) SELECT 1 userId;
```

```
SELECT userId, firstTable.name, secondTable.text 
FROM users
CROSS JOIN (
    VALUES 
    ROW(1, 'FirstName'),
    ROW(2, 'secondName')
) firstTable(id, name)
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES 
    ROW(1, 'Some Text'),
    ROW(2, 'Some other text')
) secondTable(id, text) USING (id)
 
WHERE userId = 1;
```

| userId | name | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstName | Some Text |
| 1 | secondName | Some other text |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iyrGEkne)